# Correct way to implement a stock price alert system

Tags: android

Previously, under desktop environment, to implement a stock price alert system, here is what I do.

1. Spawn a infinity running `Thread`.
2. The thread will perform stock price query from stock server.
3. The thread will perform all the necessary alerting actions based on retrieved stock price.
4. The thread sleeps for N period. (N can be let's say 30 minutes)
5. Go back to 2.

When comes to mobile environment, power efficiency usage is a major consideration. The stock alert mechanism should keep running, even when I "close" the application using back button.

There are 2 ways out from my mind.

### Use Service

1. Spawn a infinity running `Service`.
2. The service will perform stock price query from stock server.
3. The service will perform all the necessary alerting actions based on retrieved stock price.
4. The service sleeps for N period. (N can be let's say 30 minutes)
5. Go back to 2.

### Use AlarmManager

1. Install a `BroadcastReceiver` in `AlarmManager`.
2. BroadcastReceiver's `onReceive` will be triggered in next N period.
3. When BroadcastReceiver is being triggered, perform stock price query from stock server.
4. The BroadcastReceiver will perform all the necessary alerting actions based on retrieved stock price.
5. Before returning from `onReceive`,  install another `BroadcastReceiver` in `AlarmManager` for next N period.

I was wondering, **which way is better? Is there any better ways other than the 2 ways?** It seems to me `AlarmManager` is better, as we do not require to sleep for a long period, which seems sort of wasting resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AlarmManager` to trigger a `BroadcastReceiver` then have the `BroadcastReceiver` start an `IntentService`.

A `BroadcastReceiver` shouldn't do any long-running tasks but it can start a `Service` to do work. An `IntentService` (which extends `Service`) will do work on a worker thread and then self-terminate.

See [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

And [Extending the IntentService class](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService)

In other words you can combine both ways that you are considering but without a continually running `Service`.

Comment: So, before IntentService self-terminate, does it need to install BroadcastReceiver into AlarmManager again? So that the next alerting activity will be triggered after N period?

Comment: It is up to you how you create the alarm. The `AlarmManager` class has methods to `set(...)` single alarms or you can use `setRepeating(...)` which creates a repeating alarm which will trigger at the same interval until cancelled.